# Homology groups of the Dihedral Group.

Tags: group-cohomology, dihedral-groups

> I'm looking for some references for the computation of the homology in integer coefficients of the dihedral group $D_n$. Most precisely, I am interested in explicit pairing relations with the well-known integer cohomology ring.

I've found something [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_cohomology_of_dihedral_groups#Homology_groups_for_trivial_group_action), but I need some results in terms of pairing with the cohomology (which seems more understood) and not only the abstract isomorphism (as given there).

> **Some examples of the computations I'm looking for** For example, I was told that $H_2(D_n;\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}\langle d \rangle$ when $n=2 \pmod{4}$, where $d$ is the dual of $x_1\cdot x_2$, the two generators of the cohomology ring in $\mathbb{Z}_2$-coefficients.
>
> Via UCT is easy to see that for $n$ odd, $$H_5(D_{2n},\mathbb{Z})\cong \text{Ext}(H^6(D_{2n},\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$$ and by a quick application of the Bockestein e.s. one sees that such $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is generated by an integral lift of $r_5$, where $r_5$ is the generator of $H_5(D_{2n};\mathbb{Z}_2)$ dual to the generator of $H^5(D_{2n};\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\langle r^5\rangle$ (recall that $H^*(D_{2n};\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2[r]$

in general, when $n$ is even, the Bockstein e.s. doesn't provide much help, since there are $n$-torsion groups coming up.

Since the integer cohomology ring is known in terms of explicit generators (I'm especially interested in the case $n=2 \pmod{4}$) **I was wondering if homology had a nice description in terms of pairings with the cohomology generators.**